# Problems in loading the web page in brackets tool

Tags: adobe-brackets

I am using brackets tool or web development . When I click the live preview the browser opens but the web page that i develop is not getting displayed . How to trouble shoot this ?

Comment: Does the same thing happen with the simple "Getting Started" project that comes with Brackets? If not, how does your project differ from that one?

Answer (score 0):

There’s a [wiki page for troubleshooting nonfunctional live preview](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Troubleshooting#livedev).